# split x tasks among n procs (x>>n) using mpi4py

Tags: python, split, mpi4py

I'd like to split a large number of individual tasks among some processors by means of mpi4py.
The following example might illustrate my intention:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
from numpy import random

comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.Get_rank()
size=comm.Get_size()

def doSomething(x):
        return numpy.sum(x)

if rank==0:
        v=random.random((3,3))
        print 'thats v_random:\n', v

        for i in range(len(v)):
                comm.send(v[i],dest=i)

data=comm.recv(source=0)
print 'my rank is {0} and my output is {1}\n'.format(rank,doSomething(data))
```

As far as I execute it with len(v)==number of procs, everything is fine.
But e.g. when v=random.random((100,3)) its obviously not working. How is this usually accomplished?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some MPI code during my PhD using Fortran to simulate particle trajectories, we just cheated a little bit and always made the number of particles in our simulations a power of two so that they could be split evenly across the processors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found some work-around. Im pretty sure its not the most elegant way, but I rly have no idea how to accomplish it in another way. So if somebody comes across the same problem, here is one ugly but working solution:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
from numpy import random

comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.Get_rank()
size=comm.Get_size()

if(rank==0):
    v=random.random((7,3))
    if size>=len(v):
        size=len(v)
    slice_size=int(numpy.ceil(float(len(v))/float(size)))
    slice_for_last_node=len(v)-(size-1)*slice_size      
    #xtra_slices=len(v)%size

    rows=len(v)
    print "slice_size:",slice_size
    print "slice_for_last_node:",slice_for_last_node
else:
    slice_size=slice_for_last_node=rows=None

size=comm.bcast(size,root=0)
slice_size=comm.bcast(slice_size,root=0)
slice_for_last_node=comm.bcast(slice_for_last_node,root=0)
rows=comm.bcast(rows,root=0)

def doSomething(x):
        return numpy.sum(x)

if rank==0:

        print 'thats v_random:\n', v

    count=1
    cur_dest=0

        for i in range(len(v)): 
        if(count>slice_size and cur_dest<size-1):
            cur_dest+=1
            count=1
        if(cur_dest>=size-1):
            cur_dest=size-1

            comm.send(v[i],dest=cur_dest)
        count+=1

if rank<size-1:
    count=1
    while count<=slice_size: #slices per proc
        data=comm.recv(source=0)
        count+=1
        print 'my rank is {0} and my output is {1}\n'.format(rank,doSomething(data))


elif rank==size-1:
    count=1
        while count<=slice_for_last_node:
            data=comm.recv(source=0)
                count+=1
                print 'my rank is {0} and my output is {1}\n'.format(rank,doSomething(data))
```